# Congruence classes -finding the order

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

Do they mean find a general formula such that for any n we can find its order by substituting its value in the formula?  If so how do we go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The additive order of $n-1$ in $\Bbb Z_n$ is $n$.  That's it's a generator for the additive group, since $(n,n-1)=1$.

Note:  $$n-1=(n-1)\cdot 1\overset{\text{in multiplicative notation}}{\overbrace{=}}1^{n-1}\implies \lvert n-1\rvert =n/(n,n-1)=n.$$

Here's a proof of that [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4484127/1070376).

Answer (score -2):

I dont think they mean for any $n$ since no such formulas exist. For $n-1$, note that the order is just $2$ since $(n-1)^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

For addition, the order is infinity for any element in the set since we can never get back to our identity element.

Comment: Your claim that $n-1$ has order $2$ mod $n$ does in fact hold for all $n$ except $n=2$.

Comment: Why do you think that the additive order is infinity?

Comment: We are talking about $\mathbb Z_n=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$